# Multiple Selection with OL2

Tags: javascript, openlayers-2, event-listener

I created a map with some marker which can be selected and have them name appears in an external field. But i even if i am able to select multiple marker on the map ( shift command ), only one name appears in my field.

I created a vector layer loading geojson content and an event with a "featureselected" on this layer. 
But still nothing, here is my code.

```
var input = document.getElementById('input-airports');

var layerListeners = {
    featureselected:   function(e) {
        var value = '';
        value = e.feature.attributes.code  + ', ' + ' ';
        input.value = value;
    }
};

var vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Airport Markers", {
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
    eventListeners: layerListeners,
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "data.geojson",
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    "select": new OpenLayers.Style({
       pointRadius:20
    })
});
map.addLayer(vector);
```

Answer (score 1):

The event handler does not build up a feature string. It declares a fresh `value` variable each time. So it just shows the last feature that came by after a rectangle select.

You could store the `value` variable globally, and make sure the eventhandler adds to that.